# Colocar senha em um arquivo python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lock

Estou fazendo um programa no qual você seleciona o arquivo que você quer bloquear usando uma senha, clicando em um botão esse arquivo é bloqueado com uma senha definida pelo usuário. Como posso fazer com que esse arquivo só possa ser acessado com a senha?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você possa utilizar uma biblioteca como a [PyCrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) para criptografar e descriptografar seu arquivo com uma senha.

Dê uma olhada [neste tópico](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/25/aes-encryption-of-files-in-python-with-pycrypto) e [neste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852664/python-pycrypto-encrypt-decrypt-text-files-with-aes) também.

Crie uma função para `proteger()` e uma para `desproteger()`, que receba tanto o caminho do arquivo quanto a senha de acesso.

- `proteger('arq.txt', 'senha_dificil123')`
- `proteger('arq.txt', 'senha_dificil123')`

Basta dar uma lida na [documentação](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/) para entender como executar esses procedimentos.

---

Uma outra alternativa seria criar uma função para compactar o arquivo e colocar uma senha para descompactar o arquivo, como mostrado [neste tópico](https://www.howtogeek.com/170352/how-to-password-protect-files-and-folders-with-encryption/).

Para criar um arquivo criptografado `'meu_arquivo.zip`' usando a solução de código-aberto [`7-Zip`](http://www.7-zip.org/):

```
x = subprocess.call(['7z', 'a', '-pP4$$W0rd', '-y', 'meu_arquivo.zip'] + 
                     ['arquivo1.txt', 'arquivo2.txt'])
```

---

**Para instalar o `7-Zip`:**

No `Linux`, para instalar digite no terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Para descompactar manualmente o arquivo criado, digite: `$ unzip meu_arquivo.zip` e digite `'P4$$W0rd'` no prompt que aparecer pedindo a senha.

Já no `Windows` é só rodar o instalador `.exe`.